# Focus signup tab when opening auth0 Lock(v10)

Tags: javascript, authentication, locking, auth0

I have a www.domain.com WordPress Info site for my app, where I use auth0 lock10 for login/signup.
i want to have a login button and signup button in my info site that will redirect to my app.domain.com website, which is separate.

Ideally, When the user clicks login, it opens the lock widget as usual, but when they click Sign Up, it opens the lock widget and focuses the Sign Up tab instead.

there is an "initialScreen" option for lock, but that shows signup for also pressing login button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Lock options, you can turn off each tab separately by setting [allowLogin](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/configuration#allowlogin-boolean-) and [allowSignUp](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/configuration#allowsignup-boolean-) to `false`.

These options can be passed when you call `lock.show()` after the button clicks.

Comment: thanks alot, i guess thats one way of getting around it